# displaying different views on click

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am creating a really basic website in rails for learning purposes.

This functionality is something I am aiming for. Notice how the URL does not change upon clicking the tabs.

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthTabs/

I am currently stuck on this portion of my project.

In my `application.html.erb`, this page currently allows me to display a view depending on the tab I have clicked.

```
<div class="content">
    <section id="section-1">
        <!-- Home -->
        <%= yield %>
    </section>
    <section id="section-2">
        <!-- photos -->
    </section>
    <section id="section-3">
        <!-- videos -->
        three
    </section>
    <section id="section-4">
        <!-- projects -->
        four
    </section>
    <section id="section-5">
    </section>
</div>
```

My `<%= yield %>` currently loads my `home.html.erb`. I want to click other tabs to display different views (projects.html.erb, photos.html.erb, etc). However I'm not sure how to do this in Rails.

Comment: What're is in your routes? It'll be `link_to "Photos", some_path %>` but without the routes I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: @Baloo I should have made this  bit clearer sorry. I dont want to use routes as I want to put all this under one one static url

Comment: @Baloo this is a good example of something I am aiming for http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthTabs/

Comment: The switch between tabbed content without a page reload is a javascript (browser-side), not RoR (or JSP, PHP, Python, etc) trick.  Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in your example website all tabs are loaded during only one request to server. That is if you want to achieve exactly the same functionality you should render all your tabs data (photos, videos..) at once(during one request handling), you also should implement 'show/hide tabs' on clientside with the help of Html/JavaScript.

If you are new to web, I'd recommend you:

1) Implement a page, where all your data sections would be visible at once. There are plenty RoR tutorials about that on the web.

2) Then try to implement tabs. e.g. you may use [jqueryui.com/tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) as PaulProgrammer suggested or any other ui library.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your input. I'm still pretty new to web dev so I'm not quite sure how to achieve this